# Stable distribution

Tags: probability, stable-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2,\cdots, X_n $ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with common characteristic function $$f(t)=e^{-t^2-\sqrt{|t|}}.$$

$a)$ Find real numbers $\eta_n$ such that $\frac {X_1+ X_2+\cdots+ X_n}{\eta_n}$ converges in distribution to a non- degenerate probability distribution as $n\to \infty$.

$b)$ What possible distributions can the limit have?

$c)$ Prove or disprove $E\left\{\left|X_1\right|\right\}$ is finite.

My attempt:

I know $\eta_n$ will be of the of $n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ where $\alpha \in (0,2]$.

Also, characteristic function of $\frac {X_1+ X_2+\cdots+ X_n}{\eta_n}$ will be $\lim_n {f\left(\frac{t}{n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\right)}^n$.

How to proceed from here?